# How do you set up grid tables in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need a hint, a big hint.

In a grid, say 500 by 500, I need to know the value of that square. The answer would be yes or no. Is something there or not. Think of it as piece of graph paper; has the square been colored in, or not?

How would I set up this table up in Java? An example would be; I want to see if at location, x=400, y=400; is this square occupied or not.

I am just confused by how that’s done. Is that what arrays are used for?

If you would please include an example of how I would declare this table, how I would read from this table and how I would write to this table.

Thank you for helping out.

Comment: It depends a bit on what you are actually doing but a two dimensional array fits your immediate description: `boolean[][] table = new boolean[500][500];`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Multidimensional-array-in-Java

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **multi-dimensional array to hold the rows and columns** of a table. Then you can insert data accordingly and check whether a value is true or false using indexes. Here is a link. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidimensional-arrays-in-java/

it will make sense if you make one(multidimensional array) then print it to your screen. then you can populate it and check for values by the indexes. example [x][y] returns true